# Get signed request from facebook pageTab on external site

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get info if the visitor of my website has liked facebook page or not, without  user's authorization.

My idea is the following, I'd like to somehow load the facebook pageTab in background and get the signed request(the info if user has liked my facebook page or not).  Is this possible? -Or if it is not, how can I differently approach this problem.

Comment: "without user's authorization" thank god this is not possible... so to make it short: not possible without authorization

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access this information unless you have an access token for this user and have the permission for "user_likes".  I'm sure Facebook has the X-FRAME-OPTIONS set to DENY which would deny from being able to use the actual FB tab on your page, and even with it loaded you wouldn't have access to the iframe from the parent.

You can get callbacks when someone likes or unlikes a page by using a like button and the Facebook Javascript API, but this still doesn't give you exactly what you are looking for. I think your best bet is to ask for the user_likes permissions and then use the graph or FQL to verify the like status of the current page.

Comment: you has idea how it is done here?                                   [link](http://blicb92.blogger.ba/arhiva/2013/12/08/3619969)

Comment: I don't see anything on this page that pertains to the question. I do see an error for Facebook about this page having unsafe links?

Comment: yes the link is not working now, because it has been marked as spam I guess and is currently blocked, I was talking about the site structure, it was working without app, I think.  Can u take a look at the code?

Comment: The only code I see on this page regarding the like button is this: `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {});
` this allows you to know if someone clicked on a like button but doesn't let you know beforehand if they a current page. It's the callback I was talking about before.

Comment: Okay, I have another idea, but I'm unable to get the source code of cross-domain iframe.  Do you have any idea how can I get it? -If not, can you maybe help me implement this [link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)? And if you have time take look at these 2 too, [link](http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/03/how-to-pull-content-via-jquery-from-another-web-site-cross-domain-and-do-it-in-sharepoint-too/) and [link](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).